# jquery mask masked doesnt work. How set initial value to mask

Tags: jquery, jquery-mask

I try to set initial value with [jQuery Mask](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#removing-the-mask) but the docs doesnt say correct way to it.
I tried the next steps

```
    const options = {
        onKeyPress: (cep, e) => this.onChangeHandler(e),
        default: initialValue
    }
    $('#id').mask(maskPattern, options);
```

also

```
$('#id').mask(maskPattern, options);
$('#id').masked(initialValue);
```

But neither ways dont work.

I found a work around
`$('#id').val(initialValue).trigger('input');`
 at github issues and im going to share it in the answers, but i'm looking for the genuine way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`masked()`](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#getting-a-masked-value-programmatically) - **Gets a masked value programmatically**

You can set the value by

```
$('#id').val(initialValue).mask(maskPattern, options);
```

OR

```
$('#id').mask(maskPattern, options);
$('#id').val(initialValue).trigger('input');
```

[**More info**](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/issues/261)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what do you want to say with this: ```

masked() - Gets a masked value programmatically```. Masked doesnt work.

Comment: ```$('#id').val(initialValue).trigger('input');``` yea, i know this workaround but interested more generic way from mask lib

Comment: @AlexNikonov After deep digging the `mask` lib, I don't find a method to set value. you can use either of the above approach